# Query about XPath expression to return <div class="content-panel">

Tags: html, xpath

I want to extract `content` from a `<div>` tag from this URL ;

http://www.ireland.com/en-gb/destinations/republic-of-ireland/sligo/articles/mullaghmore

Using the inspect element, the information I want to extract in the HTML is 
`<div class="content-panel">`, the XPath for this container is:

```
//*[@id="PageContent_page_container"]/section/div[2]
```

This is the relevant portion of the page:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="PageContent_page_container" class="page-container">
        <section class="page editorial" ... >

            <div id="PageContent_content__1149779ca5de748_HeroPanel" class="hero-panel">...</div>

            <div class="content-panel"> <!-- THIS IS THE DIV SELECTED -->
                <div class="content">
                    <p id="PageContent_content__1149779ca5de748_Introduction" class="intro">This is Yeats Country. This is surfer country. This is a country of castles, seaside, and Ireland's very own Table Mountain. This is Mullaghmore, County Sligo</p>
                    <p>Jutting out of<a href="/en-gb/destinations/republic-of-ireland/sligo/articles/sligo"> Sligo&amp;rsquo;</a>s northern edge, close to the county&amp;rsquo;s border with Donegal, the small peninsula of <a href="/en-gb/destinations/republic-of-ireland/sligo/articles/mullaghmore">Mullaghmore</a> sits dramatically out into the North Atlantic.&amp;nbsp;</p>
                    <p>The waters here are not simply photogenic. They have become known for some of the most sought-after waves in surfing. Mullahgmore is notably championed for one big break in particular which <em>Surfing magazine</em> has dubbed &amp;ldquo;a mutant Irish left&amp;rdquo;. Surfing is in the blood here. The famous Irish pro-surfer and local Sligo legend, Easkey Britton, was even named after a beach called Easkey, just an hour&amp;rsquo;s drive further south of Mullaghmore. While you&amp;rsquo;re in the neighbourhood, why not head down to Strandhill and indulge in a indulge in the traditional Irish therapy/detox treatment of a warm seaweed bath courtesy of Voya Seaweed Baths.&amp;nbsp;</p>
                    <h3>Anyone for golf?</h3>
                    <p>Curving around to create a natural bay, the peninsula&amp;rsquo;s eastern coast stretches into an elegant sweep. From here, you're looking up along <a href="/en-gb/destinations/republic-of-ireland/donegal/articles/donegal">Donegal</a>&amp;rsquo;s southern borders at <a href="/en-gb/what-is-available/golf/golf-courses/destinations/republic-of-ireland/donegal/bundoran/all/1-365" target="_self">Bundoran Golf Club</a> and the point where the River Erne flows into the Atlantic. </p>
                    <h3>By the mountains and sea</h3>
                    <p>Also on this eastern side, sits the tiny village of Mullaghmore overlooked by two of Sligo&amp;rsquo;s icons. The first is <a href="/en-gb/what-is-available/natural-landscapes-and-sights/natural-landscapes/destinations/republic-of-ireland/sligo/sligo-town/all/1-87761" target="_self">Ben Bulben mountain</a>, part of the Dartry Mountains, a range shared by both Sligo and its neighbour <a href="/en-gb/destinations/republic-of-ireland/leitrim/articles/leitrim">Leitrim</a>. Ben Bulben sits on Sligo&amp;rsquo;s coast surging out towards the North Atlantic and shadowing the village of Mullaghmore. </p>
                    <h3>A poet&amp;rsquo;s land</h3>
                    <p>For many, Sligo is considered Yeats Country. For a poet so concerned with his home county and especially its landscape, there was no escaping Ben Bulben. The mountain&amp;rsquo;s most noted reference in Yeats&amp;rsquo;s poetry is in the work <em>Under Ben Bulben</em>, in which he describes horsemen who &amp;ldquo;ride the wintry dawn/Where Ben Bulben sets the scene".</p>
                    <h3>Walk in the wild</h3>
                    <p>For those wishing to become more intimately acquainted with the mountain, the Ben Bulben (Gortarowey) Looped Walk is a 4km (2.5 mile) route of easy-going terrain and some minor ascents. For a more thorough on-foot exploration of Mullaghmore, set off on the 8km (5 mile) beach and pier walk along Bunduff Strand. </p>
                    <div class="in-page-carousel">
                        <div class="content">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <figure>
                                        <img id="Page..._CarouselImage_0" src="http://.../sdp4_mullaghmore_car-1.jpg" alt="Ben Bulben Mountain" style="height:323px;width:571px;" />
                                        <figcaption id="Page..._CarrouselCaptionSection_0">Ben Bulben Mountain</figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <figure>
                                        <img id="Page..._CarouselImage_1" src="http://.../sdp4_mullaghmore_car-2.jpg" alt="..." style="height:323px;width:571px;" />
                                        <figcaption id="Page..._CarrouselCaptionSection_1">Classiebawn Castle provided by <a href="http://..." >Patryk Kosmider</a> </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <figure>
                                        <img id="Page..._CarouselImage_2" src="http://.../sdp4_mullaghmore_car-3.jpg" style="height:323px;width:571px;" />
                                        <figcaption id="Page..._CarrouselCaptionSection_2"></figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <aside class="related-items">
                        <h2>Related providers</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="Page..._Link_0" href="/.../1-62182">Strandhill Surf School</a></li>
                            <li><a id="Page..._Link_1" href="/.../1-82855">Offshore Watersports</a></li>
                            <li><a id="Page..._Link_2" href="/.../1-91302">Mullaghmore Head - Wild Atlantic Way</a></li>
                            <li><a id="Page..._Link_3" href="/.../1-9850">Mullaghmore Sailing Club and Centre Ltd</a></li>
                            <li><a id="Page..._Link_4" href="/.../1-87095">Yeats Country Hotel, Spa and Leisure Club</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                    <p>Few images of Mullaghmore, and for that matter Sligo, will fail to include Classiebawn Castle. Sitting in a modest rise in an evergreen spread of field about a hundred metres from the sea, there&amp;rsquo;s an air of Disney whimsy about Classiebawn. Instantly recognisable by its conical turret, building of the castle was begun by the British statesman. Classiebawn is privately owned, but well worth a visit before you set back on your Wild Atlantic Way journey.</p>
                    <p><strong>Geographical coordinates:</strong> Latitude: 54.465546; Longitude: -8.449455</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    ...
```

I have tried many different combinations of XPath in google docs to return the text but I am not getting all of the text content within `<div class="content-panel">` returned.

If I use the expression `//div/p/text()` all of the text is returned as separate rows but I need all of the text from each `<p>` tag in a single field.

If anyone can advise that would be great. Thank you.
Ali

Comment: Do you want all of the text from all `<p>` elements concatenated? What about the text in the `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<li>`. Are they to be included too?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want all the text contents, you can enclose your expression inside `string()`:

```
string(//*[@id="PageContent_page_container"]/section/div[2])
```

or `normalize-space()` if you wish to get rid of the extra spaces:

```
normalize-space(//*[@id="PageContent_page_container"]/section/div[2])
```

If you want to select individual elements that contain text, you can add extra location steps to them from your context node to get nodesets (from where you can extract individual nodes), for example:

1) The text in the second paragraph:

```
string(//*[@id="PageContent_page_container"]/section/div[2]//p[2])
```

2) A node-set containing all `<h3>` and `<h2>` headers (you can loop and extract the text for each one):

```
//*[@id="PageContent_page_container"]/section/div[2]//*[name() = 'h3' or name() = 'h2']
```